# Magento 2 Complete extension translation

Tags: magento2, php, localisation

I have created a dictionary with this command:

```
php bin/magento --output="lang.csv" i18n:collect-phrases app/code/NewModule
```

This extension has files also into the `app/design` directory, does I need to create a dictionary from this directory?